# mixing virtual function with overload regular functions?

Tags: c++

Saw the following code in the project:

```
class Base
{
...
    virtual double Function(int i) const;

...
};

class SubClass : public Base
{
    virtual double Function(int i) const;
    double Function(std::vector<int> vecInts) const;
    double Function(std::map<int> mapInts) const;
};
```

I don't feel comfortable about this design. I knew we should avoid overload virtual functions but here the case is a little different.

Question> Is there a design flaw here?

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nope, it's okay. Overloading `virtual` functions is fine. *Hiding* virtual functions is what you should be cautious about.

In your case, you're overriding the base version and providing two more overloads. So no hiding occurs.

Answer (score 3):

It is not a design flaw. It is perfectly fine.

- As long as you are not using dynamic dispatch the functions in derived class will **[hide](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/hiding-rule.html)** the base class function and the appropriate overloaded function in Derived class will be selected.(*First 3 outputs in below sample program*).
- In case of dynamic dispatch the appropriate overidden function(*remember that the overidden function is the one which takes `int` as argument*) will be called depending on actual *type* of the object(*Last 3 outputs in below sample*).

Consider the **[sample program](http://ideone.com/2HkTjN)** to make it clearer:

```
#include<iostream>
class Base
{
public:
    virtual double Function(int i) const{std::cout<<"\nIn Base int version";}
};

class SubClass : public Base
{
public:
    virtual double Function(int i) const{std::cout<<"\nIn Derived int version";}
    double Function(std::string str) const{std::cout<<"\nIn Derived string version";}
    double Function(double i) const {std::cout<<"\nIn Derived double version";}
};

int main()
{
    SubClass obj;
    obj.Function(10);
    obj.Function(10.1);
    obj.Function("Hello"); 

    Base Bobj;
    Bobj.Function(10.2);

    Base *ptr = new Base;
    ptr->Function(10.5);

    Base *ptr2 = new SubClass; 
    ptr2->Function(10);
    ptr2->Function(10.5);

    delete ptr;
    delete ptr2;
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
In Derived int version
In Derived double version
In Derived string version
In Base int version
In Base int version
In Derived int version
In Derived int version
```

Notice the last two outputs in specific,.

Comment: Example clears the OP. Just a Nitpick(It fails to compile as is) - Your definitions of Base::Function and Subclass::Function should have return statements to return a double as its prototype says. e.g. return 1.5;

Comment: True, I didn't compile with option to treat warnings as errors & I am typing through a phone right now so will add this to the Todo list.

Answer (score 1):

There is no flaw. From Effective C++, item 34:

> Pure virtual functions specify inheritance of interface only.
>
> Simple (impure) virtual functions specify inheritance of interface
>   plus inheritance of a default implementation.
>
> Non-virtual funcitons specify inheritance of interface plus
>   inheritance of a mandatory implementation.

Since Function(int i) is a virtual function and not a Non-virtual function, its default implementation may be overriden in the base class. If it would be a Non-virtual function, it would then be a mandatory implementation, not to be overriden, to ensure the "is-a" relationship in the class hierarchy.